# Unexplained gq indentation issue

Tags: indentation, formatting

I insert this text in Vim:

```
t tttt ttttttttt tt tttt tt ttt tttttt-tttt-ttttttt
tttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt ttttt ttt ttt tttttt
ttttttt tttt ttttttt: ttttttt tt ttttttt, ttttttt tt tttttt, tttttt tt ttttttt,
tttttt tt tttttt ttt. t tttttt tt ttt (tttt) ttttttt-tttttt-tt-ttttttt tttttt
for the "tttttt in ttttttt" part of the issue (in the previous week I have
worked on the "objects in objects" part). This part is about making it
possible for the end user to add arrays in objects. First of all I checked
that the current implementation allows putting arrays in objects at least
from the schema passed to the plugin constructor.
```

then I visually select all these lines and press `gq`. The contents become:

```
t tttt ttttttttt tt tttt tt ttt tttttt-tttt-ttttttt
tttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt ttttt ttt ttt tttttt
ttttttt tttt ttttttt: ttttttt tt ttttttt, ttttttt tt tttttt, tttttt tt ttttttt,
tttttt tt tttttt ttt. t tttttt tt ttt (tttt) ttttttt-tttttt-tt-ttttttt tttttt
for the "tttttt in ttttttt" part of the issue (in the previous week I have
    worked on the "objects in objects" part). This part is about making it
    possible for the end user to add arrays in objects. First of all I checked
    that the current implementation allows putting arrays in objects at least
    from the schema passed to the plugin constructor.
```

Please explain to me why there is that whitespace at the beginning of the last four lines. Is it possible that the first word (`for`) on the fifth line, which in some programming languages starts a `for` loop, makes Vim think it should start a new indented block of code, even if these lines are in an unsaved file or in a Markdown file? How can I avoid this behavior and make `gq` stop inserting that whitespace?

My `comments` setting has the default value: `s1:/*,mb:*,ex:*/,://,b:#,:%,:XCOMM,n:>,fb:-`. You can see my `.vimrc` file [here](https://github.com/silviubogan/dotfiles/blob/master/.vimrc).

**Update:** My `fo` (`formatoptions`) option has the value `tcq`, the `formatexpr` and `formatprg` options are empty.

Comment: And if the file is saved/not new, any difference?

Comment: It is the same behavior.

Comment: Then you could remove that information from the text in order to make the problem simpler.

Comment: @GabrielPetrovay, thank you for the feedback! `:-)` I updated the question.

Comment: what is your 'fo' option and 'formatexpr' and formatprg option?

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt, I have updated the question with the details you requested.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The problem is that you have set `smartindent` in your `~/.vimrc`. The `smartindent` options causes Vim to assume that your text is some C-like programming language when indenting. Among other things, it treats `for` like a keyword and gives an extra level of indentation to the line following. See

```
:help 'smartindent'
:help 'cinwords'
```